# Selected Row Datagrid sum cell

Tags: vb.net

I have `gridview` for invoice need sum cells

```
Number     Description      Price     Qty    Total     Discount    Grand Total
5050       Screen           50        1      50        5           45
6060       Case             100       2      200       50          150
```

When I change value of `price`,`qty` or `discount`, I need it to dynamically calculate total and grand total.

Comment: sorry i want every cell updated when i change any value total=price*qty

Comment: grand total= total-discount

Answer (score 0):

I did a small example of your needs (https://github.com/anderson-rancan/stackoverflow_31950624), so:

- use properties, so your data binding can properly use your code

  ```
  Private _description As String

  Public Property Description() As String
      Get
          Return Me._description
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          If Not (value = Me._description) Then
              Me._description = value
              Me.NotifyPropertyChanged()
          End If
      End Set
  End Property
  ```
- use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to update your form and other structures

  ```
  Public MustInherit Class BusinessObject
      Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

      Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

      Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
          RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
      End Sub

  End Class
  ```
- add your bussiness rules at your bussiness objects, so they can update themselves

  ```
  Private Sub Recalculate()
      Me.GrandTotal = Me._shopItems.Sum(Function(item) item.GrandTotal)
  End Sub
  ```
- add data binding to your form objects

  ```
  Me._binding = New BindingSource()
  Me._binding.DataSource = New Shop()
  Me._binding.DataMember = "ShopItems"

  Me.ShopItemsDataGridView.DataSource = Me._binding
  Me.ShopItemsDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True
  ```

With those methods, you'll be able to automatic recalculate your totals and update your form.

Please, if you need further information, Google it for WinForms DataBinding or something similar.